# SQL Advance Limit Like To display only top result of each group

Tags: sql

For example i have set of:

```
Value A    |   Apple
Value B    |   Apple
Value C    |   Orange
Value D    |   Orange
```

what I want, is a query to get top result, something like this:

```
Value A    |   Apple
Value C    |   Orange
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I answered with the data you gave me, but you need to give more details in you questions.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @terary I'm not getting any error , what I do have is a complete list of evething. Now, I wan't to limit these result in only 1 or 3. per Apple, per Orange.

Comment: @David Faber I'm using MySql

Comment: What I'm looking for is something like with the answer of @Sandro Eric, but what if, first 5 results per Orange, or per Apple in one result set.

Answer (score 2):

For your data, you can do:

```
select min(col1), col2
from table
group by col2;
```

In SQL, tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no concept of a first or last row, unless another column specifies the ordering.  In your case, the minimum happens to work. If by "top" you mean "first", then you need another column to specify the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

you can distinct with order by for it.

```
select distinct field1, field_in_group_by 
from your_table 
group by field_in_group_by 
order by field_in_group_by desc
```